# Where is the help function defined or located?

Tags: functions, help-system

I'm trying to find where the `help` function/command is defined.
So far I tried:

```
:verbose function help
```

but since the `h` isn't in uppercase, it doesn't work (not sure if it's even a function at this point...)

Tried:

```
:verbose command help
```

This reports that it's not user-defined, though it's obvious since it's in the default Vim.

Last, I tried going into the `/usr/share/vim/` directory, and running a mass grep script to search for any string/and or file that have `function! help`, `help` etc.

I looked into the Vim manual but I am  not sure I found anything so far. Any (no pun intended) help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:help` command, just like every other built-in commands, is defined in the C code that is compiled into the Vim binary.

You can find in [`src/ex_cmds.c`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/src/ex_cmds.c#L5054-L5058) in the Vim source code.

(Note also that user-defined commands are only allowed to start with an uppercase, precisely to separate them from built-in commands. Also, functions and commands are completely separate namespaces, a function needs to be evaluated with `:call` or as part as an expression, while a command is directly invoked after the `:` that puts you in Ex mode.)

Comment: is there a command or function to know where one is located/defined? (for other things beside `help`). Since I'm assuming that not every builtin are in the C code, though that would help in that case too.

Comment: Yes, every built-in command and function in Vim is defined in C code.